# Creating large dataset from multiple CSV's without running out of memory

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, memory

I am working on creating a pandas dataframe object from the combination of a few CSV files. The issue is, I run into memory problems when I try to load everything into one dataframe. I have explored the option of using the "chunk size" parameter when loading but all of the applications of this say that the CSV's should have the same amount of row's, where this is not the case in my project.

The features are spread across multiple CSV's and are each related to an observation by a corresponding index #. However, not all of the CSV's have a row for each observation. I want to combine all of the CSV's into one dataframe (or a series of dataframes which each contain all columns) by matching the index columns

Example:

- CSV1 has 2 million rows.
- CSV2 has 1.5 million, 1 million of which have matching index numbers to CSV1.
- Both CSV's should be combined into a dataframe which has 2.5 million rows; the 1 Million shared, the 1 million unique to CSV1, and the 0.5 million unique to CSV2
- This process is then repeated for an additional 9 csv's

Does anyone have some advice as to how I can accomplish this? I expect the end result to be a batch of dataframes, but i would like them to all have the same amount of columns and different rows. Thank you.

Edit:
So I have been working on it some more and have gotten a bit more insight to the problem and it may not necessarily be a size issue but maybe something in my programming and memory allocation.

The CSV files are not Gb's in size, rather, the folder containing all of the CSV files is only about 100 Mb. I figured it was mostly object data that was causing the massive expansion when converted to a pandas data frame. I followed a tutorial on decreasing the size of a data frame and started to run into some problems at the same point.

Firstly here is my code...

```
import os
import urllib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

FARS_PATH = "Data/2016"

# Function to reduce integer and float data types
def number_downcast(int_columns, float_columns):
    converted_int = int_columns.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='unsigned')
    converted_float = float_columns.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float')

    return converted_int, converted_float

# Function to reduce objects to categories
def object_to_category(object_columns):
    converted_categories = pd.DataFrame()

    for col in object_columns.columns:
        num_unique_values = len(object_columns[col].unique())
        num_total_values = len(object_columns[col])
        if num_unique_values / num_total_values < 0.5:
            converted_categories.loc[:,col] = object_columns[col].astype('category')
        else:
            converted_categories.loc[:,col] = object_columns[col]

    return converted_categories

# Function to reduce whole dataframe using above functions
def optimize_dataframe(dataset):
    int_columns = dataset.select_dtypes(include=['int'])
    float_columns = dataset.select_dtypes(include=['float'])
    object_columns = dataset.select_dtypes(include=['object']).copy()

    converted_ints, converted_floats = number_downcast(int_columns, float_columns)
    converted_categories = object_to_category(object_columns)

    optimized_dataset = dataset.copy()

    optimized_dataset[converted_ints.columns] = converted_ints
    optimized_dataset[converted_floats.columns] = converted_floats
    optimized_dataset[converted_categories.columns] = converted_categories

    return optimized_dataset

# Indexing column is "ST_CASE"
def load_the_data(data_path = DATA_PATH):
    FISRT_csv_path = os.path.join(data_path, "one.csv")
    SECOND_csv_path = os.path.join(data_path, "two.csv")
    THIRD_csv_path = os.path.join(data_path, "three.csv")
    FOURTH_csv_path = os.path.join(data_path, "four.csv")
    FIFTH_csv_path = os.path.join(data_path, "five.csv")
    SIXTH_csv_path = os.path.join(data_path, "six.csv")
    SEVENTH_csv_path = os.path.join(data_path, "seven.csv")


    # FIRST data has 34,439 rows and 52 columns
    # FIRST data before optimization: float64(2), int64(47), object(3), 18.5 Mb
    # FIRST data after optimization: category(3), float32(2), uint16(3), uint32(2), uint8(42), 4.8 Mb
    FIRST_data = pd.read_csv(FIRST_csv_path, low_memory=False)

    # SECOND data has 52,231 rows and 105 columns
    # SECOND Data before optimization: int64(87), object(18), 94.3 Mb 
    # SECOND Data after optimizaton: category(17), object(1), uint16(13), uint32(3), uint(71), 10.7 Mb
    SECOND_data = pd.read_csv(SECOND_csv_path, low_memory=False)
    merged_data = pd.merge(FIRST_data, SECOND_data, left_on="ST_CASE", right_on="ST_CASE", how="left")
    del FIRST_data, SECOND_data   # Remove excess dataframes from memory
    merged_data = optimize_dataframe(merged_data)

    # THIRD data has 85,469 rows and 68 colunns
    # THIRD data before optimization: float64(10), int64(58), 44.4 Mb
    # THIRD data after optimization: float32(10), uint16(9), uint32(1), uint8(48). 9 Mb
    THIRD_data = pd.read_csv(THIRD_csv_path, low_memory=False)
    THIRD_data = optimize_dataframe(THIRD_data)
    merged_data = pd.merge(merged_data, THIRD_data, left_on="ST_CASE", right_on="ST_CASE", how="left")
    del THIRD_data   # Remove excess dataframes from memory

    # FOURTH data has 1,367 rows and 60 columns
    # FOURTH data before optimization: int64(43), object(17), 1.9 Mb
    # FOURTH data after optimization: category(16), object(1), uint16(3), uint32(2), uint64(1), uint8(37) 262.9 Kb
    FOURTH_data = pd.read_csv(FOURTH_csv_path, low_memory=False)
    merged_data = pd.merge(merged_data, FOURTH_data, left_on="ST_CASE", right_on="ST_CASE", how="left")
    del FOURTH_data   # Remove excess dataframes from memory
    merged_data = optimize_dataframe(merged_data)

    # FIFTH data has 7,448 rows and 24 columns
    # FIFTH data before optimization: int64(23), object(1) 1.8 Mb
    # FIFTH data after optimization: category(1), uint16(5), uint32(1), uint8(17), 236.1 Kb
    FIFTH_data = pd.read_csv(FIFTH_csv_path, low_memory=False)
    FIFTH_data = pd.merge(merged_data, FIFTH_data, left_on="ST_CASE", right_on="ST_CASE", how="left")
    del FIFTH_data   # Remove excess dataframes from memory
    merged_data = optimize_dataframe(merged_data)

    # SIXTH data has 102,861 rows and 8 columns
    # SIXTH data before optimization: int64(8), 6.3 Mb
    # SIXTH data after optimization: uint16(1), uint32(1), uint8(6), 1.2 Mb
    SIXTH_data = pd.read_csv(SIXTH_csv_path, low_memory=False)
    merged_data = pd.merge(merged_data, SIXTH_data, left_on="ST_CASE", right_on="ST_CASE", how="left")
    del SIXTH_data   # Remove excess dataframes from memory
    merged_data = optimize_dataframe(merged_data)

    # SEVENTH data has 122,022 rows and 10 columns
    # SEVENTH data before optimization: int64(10), 9.3 Mb
    # SEVENTH data after optimization unit16(1), uint32(1), uint8(8) 1.6 Mb
    SEVENTH_data = pd.read_csv(SEVENTH_csv_path, low_memory=False)
    SEVENTH_data = pd.merge(merged_data, SEVENTH_data, left_on="ST_CASE", right_on="ST_CASE", how="left")
    del SEVENTH_data   # Remove excess dataframes from memory
    merged_data = optimize_dataframe(merged_data)

    return merged_data
```

Then I run this to get information about the returned data frame:

```
data_test_set = load_the_data()
data_test_set.info(memory_usage='deep')
```

After the seventh CSV file is where the memory error occurs. However I tried running the information command after every CSv and noticed that even after the third CSV the information returns this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 162518 entries, 0 to 162517
Columns: 223 entries, STATE_x to LOCATION
dtypes: category(20), float32(12), object(1), uint16(25), uint32(4), uint8(161)
memory usage: 61.8 MB
```

Which leads me to believe I may not be combining the dataframes incorrectly due to there being too many rows for a combination of the first three.

Edit #2: There's a possibility that the indexing of this dataset is a bit more complicated than just matching that one column, as there may be 3-4 distinct observations for each of that index which is why the files are expanding so drastically.

Comment: where is your code? what have you tried?

Comment: maybe see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13059/merging-large-csv-files-in-pandas

Comment: @data_garden Please see my edits to the original question

Comment: @avigil I'm not sure those methods are xactly fitting. see my edits, the CSV's are not actually THAT large in size.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my working process when the csv file size is too big . I chunk it into database, and query it out with the columns I need. Also , if you need do calculation , you can also chunk it within for loop and store the final result in database again.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

count = 0
con = sa.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:pwd@localhost:00001/r')
#con = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///XXXXX.db') SQLite
chunks = pd.read_csv('yourfile', chunksize=10000, encoding="ISO-8859-1",
                     sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
```

Base on your file size, you'd better optimized the chunksize, for example I always using total row number divided by 30, but it all depends on your data type

```
for chunk in chunks:
        chunk.to_sql(name='Table', if_exists='append', con=con)
        count += 1
        print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, the answer was that I need to pay more attention to my massive data set. The indexing column only allows for a total of 50,000 different values and so I need to find some other way to combine them. Perhaps writing individual functions that combine the necessary CSV's for the given applications.